# Unable to send a http POST request to ASP.NET web api Controller using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, node.js, asp.net-web-api, xmlhttprequest

There is a node.js server and I'm going to call my web api controller when a client connected with node.js server using a websocket. Im' using socket.io to connect client with node.js server, then node.js server sends a xhr POST request to web api controller. but getting the response as,
 "{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:4928/api/Player'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'Player' that matches the request."}"

**Web API Method**

```
    public class PlayerController : ApiController
{
      public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    public string Post(string value)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

**Node.js**

```
 var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var querystring = require('querystring');
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('A user connected ' + socket.handshake.address);
    PostRequest(socket.handshake.address);
    //Whenever someone disconnects this piece of code executed
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('A user disconnected ' + socket.handshake.address);
    });
});


function PostRequest(data) {

    var url = "http://localhost:4928/api/Player";
    var params = "value=" + data;/* querystring.stringify({ "value": data })*/
    xhr.open('POST', url, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {//Call a function when the state changes.
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
        console.log(xhr.responseText);

    }
    xhr.send(querystring.stringify({ value: "sss" }));

}


http.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Anyway this is working when I'm call the get method sending a xhr get request

Comment: Try putting `[HttpPost]` attribute on your Post action method.

Comment: @MohsinMehmood The result is same. But when I remove parameters from web api post method and call without passing parameters it's working. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You need to inform Web API to look for the *value* [parameter in the Request body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-frombody) since you're not sending data via query string.  Try modifying your Post action signature:

```
public string Post([FromBody]string value)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: If he is passing the value in query parameters then [FromUrl] attribute will be there!

Comment: @OneManBand Now the Post method is calling after  adding [FromBody] attribute. But the Value parameter is getting null.

Comment: Hmm.  Try using JSON.stringify() instead of querystring.stringify().